# Calling server side method with parameter on click on a div inside a repeater

Tags: asp.net, onclick, repeater

I have a page where I show the characters of a user. Using a repeater, I create a div for each character with different informations on the characters taken from my DB. I want to be able to call a method server side that use my characterId as a parameter when I click on one of the divs.

I tried using onclick on the div tag. Using an anchor. Using a display:none button and call it when clicking the div, I tried several weird things that didn't make much sense to me. I'm getting out of ideas. I'm fine with using javascript if needed.

Here the code for my page

```
<asp:Repeater ID="VK_Character_CharacterNotSelected_rptCharacter" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="divCharacterNotSelected_divCharacterPanel" 
                     onclick='<%# "SelectCharacter_Click("+Eval("CharacterId")+")" %>'
                     runat="server" 
                     id="VK_Character_CharacterNotSelected_divCharacter">
```

And the codebehind

```
protected void SelectCharacter_Click(int characterId)
{
    Stuff....
}
```

Thank you for any help provided.

Edit: After following King A.Majid answer, I can call the server side method with my parameter but I need to call the button onclick when I click on my div.

Edit 2: I thought about using ItemDataBound to set it but dunno how to set a div onclick

Edit 3: Using linkbutton instead but it mix up with the CSS I have on links. Here the image to show:

[image]

Edit 4: Problem solved. Just added extra CSS to my page to fix the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LinkButton`. It is rendered as a link on a browser so you can add whatever you want inside that link.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="VK_Character_CharacterNotSelected_rptCharacter" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" 
            OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" 
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CharacterId") %>'>
            <div class="divCharacterNotSelected_divCharacterPanel">...</div>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var characterId = e.CommandArgument;
}
```

Comment: Yes this work perfectly! Only problem is it turn all my text in my div to the CSS I gave my links. :s

Comment: Edited my question with a screenshot

Comment: It is just a easy fix by tweaking a few CSS rules. For example, `.divCharacterNotSelected_divCharacterPanel a, .divCharacterNotSelected_divCharacterPanel a:link, .divCharacterNotSelected_divCharacterPanel a:visited, .divCharacterNotSelected_divCharacterPanel a:active, .divCharacterNotSelected_divCharacterPanel a:hover { color: #fff; }`

Comment: God I hate CSS. :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Bro,

to achieve your Goal use the Following , Define the Button as the Following inside the Repeater:

```
<asp:Button Id="SelectCharacter" CommandName="SelectCharachter" runat="server"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CharachterId") %>' />
```

In Code Behind :

```
  protected void VK_Character_CharacterNotSelected_rptCharacter_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
         switch (e.CommandName)
                {
case "SelectCharachter":
string _SelectedCharachter=e.CommandArgument.ToString();
break;

}
}
```

So you dont Need to Handle the OnClick as long as its inthe repeater the Repeater_Command Event would take care of it:

Regards

Comment: I'll try that. It looks like what I need. Will tell if it works

Comment: It's working great for the button. Only one thing I need is to make the div onclick event to trigger the button onclick. Problem is, since it's in a repeater, the button ID is all weird and funky